# React.js - Scan a document

Tags: reactjs

Hope everyone is doing fine :)

Does anyone know if it's possible to scan a document from an external scanner and receive it in React.js? I've done some research and only found npm packages for React Native, but nothing related to React.js. A possible solution was to install react-camera package and use the scanner as a "camera" component. What do you think? :)

Thanks in advance. Stay safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. To enable an external driver (like a scanner or printer), you can use react-html5-camera-photo (scan) or react-to-print (printer). Here's the link:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html5-camera-photo
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print

Then just follow the documentation and it will be good :)
Stay safe

Comment: Did you get these to work with an external document scanner?

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a document scanner in React.js and have also added functionality for filters. You can find the repository for the document scanner here.

documents scanner repository: https://github.com/prem-acharya/document-scanner

you can use react-image-crop: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop